# How to delete two rows of every three rows in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the following sample of a data sheet:

```
May 1 2017
May 1 2017
May 1 2017
May 2 2017
May 2 2017
May 2 2017
```

I want to remove 2 of each three rows, how can I do this in excel? so what I want is this:

```
May 1 2017
May 2 2017
etc...
```

EDIT

I dont want to remove duplicates, I just want to remove 2 of every three rows, it's okay if there was 4 duplicates or 5 and only 2 were removed.

Comment: Loop backwards with a for loop in vba.  Use a Step -3.  Delete the two rows below each step.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think the only issue with him doing that is that it sounds like there might be some rows of 4 or 5

Comment: @dwirony look at the last sentence.  The op does not care if duplicates are left.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ahh I suppose if every date has at least 2 copies of itself then it's no problem, I was thinking that it could accidentally delete some dates while stepping back 3 at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following formula in the first row of data in a blank column:

```
=MOD(Row(1:1)-1,3)
```

Then filter the data on the `0`

Then if you want those values permanently copy and paste the result to another range.

Comment: hmm, idk why this didnt work, at first I had 1022148 rows, after this I had 1022146 rows, so it only removed two, but it should have worked, not sure why it didnt.

Comment: it is showing 1,4,7,10 so i'm very confused as to why it didnt work